# android - LocationManager vs FusedLocation

Tags: android, location

I tried Fused Location (GoogleApiClient) and it was inaccurate when getting a location, it gave me my previous location even when I ask for a new (current) one, I asked for 10 requests (in order to be as accurate as possible) but after 4-6 times it simply stopped requesting and the ones it did get, were very inaccurate (881m accuracy).

On the other hand, when using LocationManager, it always gave me my location more or less, it never stopped in the middle for no reason and in general was much more stable.

So in what way fused location is better than location manager?

Answer (score 1):

Weird!!! **Fused location** should be faster and should provide more accurate location.

Make sure you are requesting location updates

```java
LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
    mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this
);
```

instead of getting last known location

```java
mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
    mGoogleApiClient
);
```

and you're using `LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY`(GPS).

Main difference between **Fused Location** and **Location Manager** is the latter does not depend on **Google Play Services**.

Comment: You just gave me another reason to use LocationManager :) I did all you wrote, fused location is faster, no doubt about that but I'm looking for accuracy, not speed. I stood near a window (partially indoors). I put debug in OnLocationChanged of the fused location and location manager and the first one stopped when it felt like with accuracy of 881. With location manager, it stopped requesting only when I told it to (after 10 times) and the accuracy was 39m and the location was perfect!

Comment: `Fused Location` is more accurate.....I've used both and I found `Fused Location` getting location as soon as I start the app, with `Location Manager` I had to wait for 2-5 mins. `Location Manager` is easier though. At the least get your Fused Location code working.

Comment: I stood at one place and requested my location. It was OK. I tried the same while walking, the location was the same as before. I thought I wasn't walking correctly so I closed my app, walked for 200m and reopened it to try again. The first time, gave me my previous location (200m ago), trying again, gave me the current location.

Answer (score -3):

Fused location doesn't work on a new handset or if a person has never used google.maps to get directions.

To get fused loction work you must ask the user to open once Google maps and get my location..but once that is done then fused location is best.

But for location finder in any app we can use mylocation layer and that gives accurate results even if the handset or user has never been exposed to maps..